# What is the best way to keep the quality of fried food while being delivered?

Tags: storage-method, french-fries, catering

How does one keep fried food hot while staying crispy for delivery? There are plenty of heating bags but I need one especially for French fries and other fried foods. Are there any techniques that keep french fries fresh during transportation?

Comment: We have a discussion on the closure of the question on Meta: https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3544/reopen-request-on-question-about-fried-foods/3545#3545

Comment: @rumtscho how is this question a duplicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest scourge of fried foods is moisture. What you need is a dry absorbent vessel. I have seen paper bags packed with paper towels and left open to vent steam used successfully for what you are trying to achieve.